# When is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 |z_k|^2$ a convergent series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have the space
$$l^2 = \{z=(z_k)_{k=1}^\infty: z_k \in \mathbb{C}, ||z||^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty |z_k|^2 < \infty\} .$$
I am currently working on a task which considers the subspace
 $$ S = \{z \in l^2: \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 |z_k|^2 < \infty\}, $$
but I have no intuition how elements in there look like. I am wondering what conditions I need to have a convergent series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 |z_k|^2$.

I know that $a_k = k^2 |z_k|^2$ has to be a sequence converging to $0$. Since $k^2$ is not convergent, I need to have a constraint on $|z_k|^2$. One possibility would be that $z_k$ only has finitely many non-zero coordinates. Then we have a finite sum and everything is fine.
Another possibility would be that $|z_k|^2$ is "much greater" than $k^2$, whatever that means.

Is there a more general constraint on $a_k = k^2 |z_k|^2$ to have convergent $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ than $z_k \neq 0$ for only finitely many $k$?

Comment: Maybe for some intuition it helps that the sequence diverges when $$|z_k|=\frac{1}{k^3}$$ but it converges when $$|z_k|=\frac{1}{k^{3+\varepsilon}}$$ for any $\varepsilon>0$

Comment: Thank you, is there also some inequality I can use that gives some constant $C>0$ such that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 |z_k|^2 \leq  C \sum_{k=1}^\infty |z_k|^2 $$

Comment: No, unfortunately this doesn't work. For example if $|z_k|=\frac1k$ then the left-hand side is $\infty$ but the right hand side is $\frac{\pi^2}6<\infty$